# WKWebView not open Google Wallet

Tags: objective-c, swift, wkwebview

i created `WKWebView` and opened checkout page from [Shopify Service](https://www.shopify.com/)

I see this screen on Payment page: 
[image]

And when i click on `Buy with Google Wallet` - nothing happened. I read a lot about `target = _blank` and problem with `WKWebView`. I added `WKUIDelegate` and use `createWebViewWithConfiguration` method - but it not work.

Does anyone know how to go to Google Wallet from here?